# Filter Solr suggestions using context filter query based on one field

Tags: solr, lucene, autosuggest, search-suggestion

My index consists of documents that **can** contain a field named `rei`.
I currently have a `suggester` setup with the following config:

```xml
<lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">contSuggester</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_suggest</str>
    <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
    <str name="buildOnOptimize">true</str>
    <str name="buildOnStartup">true</str>
    <str name="field">contrat_lib_s_sugg</str>
    <str name="contextField">rei</str>
    <str name="highlight">false</str>
</lst>
```

I'm trying to filter out suggestions based on that `rei` field. I only want to get suggestions from documents that either contain the value "CA1701", or don't have that `rei` field at all.

To my knowledge, you can't use a `filter query` for the `/suggest` component. I'm using the `contextField` for this purpose, but I can't seem to find the solution.

I know how to do this using a `filter query`:

```
rei:CA1701 OR (*:* NOT rei:[* TO *])
```

but I can't translate it in the `suggest.cfq` syntax, as I can't specify the field name. The following query only gives me suggestions from documents that contain the value "CA1701" inside the `rei` field:

```
/suggest.q=super&suggest.dictionary=contSuggester&suggest.cfq=CA1701
```